# The repository pattern with DI

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

So far, I thought about repositories as "recipe book", where I'd put pretty much every query I had with my model.

For example :

```
Model -> Post
Repo -> PostRepository with Post injected via DI
Method -> find() uses $this->post->find
```

That was great so far to reduce duplication and helped with unit testing.

But then I encountered a case where I need a repository in another repository.
And then I needed that first repository in the other one.
I injected these two in each other constructor.

My tests would fail and would throw a limit exhaustion error. Infinite injection was the problem.

After a little thought about this I came up with 3 potential solutions :

1) Only inject Repos in methods. That'll solve my actual problem, but I'll have to take extra care that I never inject the same repo and go back to case 1. I hate this option.

2) Repositories should be about concepts, not about models. If I need a repository in another one, maybe they share the same concept and that should be extracted to another repository.
That won't solve the problem forever since I feel like I'll have to inject one of these repository in another one at some point if application grows.
I'm kinda "ok" with this option.

3) I need another type/level of class. One that would be querying ONLY, at the lowest level, on the model. These would be used by any repository in any way needed, and that should never cause any problem. That also helps not doing a mistake cause by problem 1). I prefer this option the most.

I feel like the best solution might be a mixup of everything above, but I'm kinda lost at this point.
This is obviously all in a Laravel environnment, even though I feel like this is more abstract than framework or even language level.

Thanks.

EDIT :

As it's been asked in a comment, here's a simple example of code where I need the query in another repo :

```
class PostRepository {
    private $post;
    private $commentRepository;

    public function __construct(Post $post, CommentRepository $commentRepository) {
        $this->post = $post;
        $this->commentRepository = $commentRepository;
    }

    public function hasComments($post) {
        return $this->commentRepository->countCommentsForPost($post->id) > 0;
    }

    public function exists($post) {
        // ...
    }
}

class CommentRepository {
    private $comment;
    private $postRepository;

    public function __construct(Comment $comment, PostRepository $postRepository) {
        $this->comment = $comment;
        $this->postRepository = $postRepository;
    }

    public function create($content, $post) {
        if ($this->postRepository->exists($post)) {
            return $this->comment->create(['content' => $content, 'post_id' => $post->id]);
        }
    }

    public function countCommentsForPost($post) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That's a very simple (and not too smart) example and you could argue that the Post model should have a "comments" relationship but I still feel like this kind of logic is in the wrong place here, and I don't like putting it in the controller. That code only will get an infinite loop with "automatic" DI.

Comment: Could you add a (simplified) example of when you need access to another repository? In Symfony-terms (which uses repositories for db stuff) what you're describing sounds like a service

Comment: Why inject commentRepository into PostRepository. You can inject Comment model (that even violate the single responsibilty principle) into PostRepository. You can create PostCommentRepository instead i think that will be ideal..

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I'm only creating a comment here. The logic (if) involves the postRepository but I feel like the main concept involved here is the Comment model. Also would that mean I'll need a new repository anytime I'll need a repository in another one ? I agree that violates the SRP. Even the simple if statement here violates it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, repositories are usually used everywhere but other repositories. Or well, I've never really thought of an example where you would need such a thing.

What you are describing might be a service class which might have a few repositories injected through the constructor.

Oh and, the last thing I've read about repositories gave me an interesting idea about having read only repositories which just query the database for results, but they don't save / create / update / delete stuff. These methods stay in the models because of complexity.

Here's the post I've read about this:
http://adamwathan.me/2015/02/14/active-repository-is-an-antipattern/

oh and by unit testing repositories, do you mean integration testing? because writing unit tests for stuff that already was tested might not be the best idea. (talking about Eloquent)

Update:
I just saw your update and it seems like you need the Comment model, not the whole repository. And repositories should as short as possible, usually one return statement without any ifs but I've never really run into a situation like that, so I am not sure if checking stuff there is the best idea.

Maybe do the if check somewhere else and just run the query if it passes?

Also, for some of the queries, using relationships might help you even more.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm talking about unit testing on complicated queries where I actually start by writing unit tests and make them pass. I like to be able to mock the model that I'll pass in to describe the flow of what should be called / done and what the result should be.

Comment: OK, well some people say that mocking stuff is kind of an overkill but I've never really done that, only repository integration testing which gives you a result of the query.

Comment: If I do the if check somewhere else, that'll be in my controller, and I thought that would be messy. That's why I thought of option (3), where I'd need another level using those low level repositories, but I don't know if I'm right or not.

Comment: Why not a service class? That is usually a class between the repository and the controller which does multiple things like save stuff to the database, log stuff to the database,sends a mail to the user, updates some kind of statistic etc.Whatever the scenario is, you might have more than just save the item to the database. But yeah, it really depends from project to project.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that although you can DI repository classes into other repository classes, you can't have circular DI like you have coded there. The laravel container classes that resolve DI for you will call the constructor of every class that gets DI. So what you need to do is sort out your dependency hierarchy, e.g by moving some of the common functionality down one dependency layer.

Comment: Yes I totally agree with that. That's what I thought in option (3). But how do you call this higher layer that would use these two repositories ?

Comment: That's really a design question for your app. You can certainly dependency inject any higher layer, it's just a matter of how you design it.

So for example you might want to create a repository called BlogRepository that pulled in both PostRepository and CommentRepository (DI both of those lower classes into BlogRepository). Then just DI your BlogRepository into your controller. The functionality that your controller needs should be covered by BlogRepository, and if necessary it should be able to delegate tasks downwards to the Post or Comment repositories.